# How to use same Java_Home used during installation?

Tags: java-home

We are installing agent in windows sytem using recent(at the time of installtion) version of java. At that time of installtion AGENT set its own java path according to JAVA_HOME. Now due to security concern after some interval java is updated. Since java path is not matched ,we are getting error for this agent after every java update. Also for some agent concern, its not possible to run this agent with new version of java. Suppose this agent is compataible with java 1.7, So may be its not compaitaible with 1.8. We want to run our agent using the same java ,we had at the time of installtion. Any suggection of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `JAVA_HOME` in environment variables from where `JAVA_HOME` will be set and will be used by all your applications that require JAVA. In windows you need to go `Control Panel-Advanced System Settings`- `Click Advanced tab` - `Environment variables`.
Create new in System variables and `JAVA_HOME` over there and its done. Reboot your system to view changes.

Comment: The scenario here is : There is already JAVA_HOME and default java installed in program files, but I would like to install agent and it will have its own java installations and want to keep independent of default java version.